# How to draw semi-transparent text on a graphics object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, text, transparency

I want to draw a text with 32 bit transparency on a graphics object. When I try, I only get black color in the result.

If I try to draw a line with the same semitransparent color, it works perfectly.

I have this code:

```
lBitmap As New Bitmap(32, 32, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
lGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(lBitmap)

lGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
lGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

lGraphic.Clear(Color.Transparent)

Dim lTestTransparencyColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 140, 0, 230)
lGraphic.DrawLine(New Pen(lTestTransparencyColor), 0, 0, 32, 32)

lBrush As New SolidBrush(lTestTransparencyColor)
lGraphic.DrawString("A", New Font("Arial", 12), lBrush, 0, 0)

Dim lImage As Image = lBitmap
lImage.Save("D:\Test.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

The line is drawn with the transparency applied correctly, but the text is black with no transparency.

**Edit:**
If I set a solid color as background on the Graphics object, then the text transparency works, but I need it to be truly transparent in the result png file, not just transparent against a solid background color in the image.
This problem occurs also if I set a partial transparent color as background like this:

```
lGraphic.Clear(Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 255, 0))
```

I was thinking it may be that SolidBrush does not support transparency, but I found a predefined brush named Transparent (`Brushes.Transparent`) that was a `SolidBrush` when I looked at it in debug. I tried to use `Brushes.Transparent` as the brush when drawing the text, and it was successfully not showing at all. That means I get full transparency to work, but not partial transparency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`TextRenderingHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs.aspx) to either `SingBitPerPixel` or `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`:

```
lGraphic.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me aware of this setting! I used `TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias` instead. Then I get perfect result with semi-transparent antialiasing!

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this tutorial many times always with success:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/watermark.aspx

Hope it helps you, I'm not sure what you mean really with "32 bit transparancy" but I believe the above link tells you how it is possible to adjust the transparancy level with the alpha filter when you create the brush:

SolidBrush semiTransBrush2 = 
    new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(153, 0, 0,0));

Comment: It is only a problem when the background of the graphics object is transparent. If the background has a non-transparent color, the text transparency works. I will update my post to clarify this.